# Converting python code to shared object

Tags: python, c, cpython

I would like to prepare a shared object (.so) from a python module. I came across Cython which would a) first convert a *.pyx module to a *.c code,b) and then this *.c code would be converted to a shared object (.so). All the examples of Cython then state how this .so can be imported into python.

But, I am interested in reading this shared object from a C code. When I wrote a sample C code to read a .so, it throws a error saying that the methods that are actually present in .pyx are not present in the .so object.

I would like to know 
a) whether is it possible to read the shared objects from Cython from a different language such as C 
b) And, if the above statement is True, what changes do I have to make in my code so that I would be able to read a shared object from C.

Thanks,

Python code (saved as square_number.pyx)

```
def square_me(int x):
    return x * x
```

Corresponding setup.py file for Cython

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("square_number.pyx"),
     )
```

Command line statements for converting the above .pyx to a .So (through cython)

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This would create a square_number.so in the same folder. Now, I renamed this to libSquareNumber.so

C code for reading the .so

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int result;

    result=square_me(2);

    printf("Sum of entered numbers = %d\n",result);

    return 0;
 }
```

When I am trying to compile and build an executable from the above command, I am getting an error

Compilation of C code:

```
gcc -L/home/USRNAME/work/cython-codes/squaring/ -Wall -o test so_reader_in_c.c -lSquareNumber
```

Error

```
so_reader_in_c.c: In function ‘main’:
so_reader_in_c.c:11:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘square_me’ [-    Wimplicit-function-declaration]
result=square_me(2);
^
/tmp/ccE5vIOH.o: In function `main':
so_reader_in_c.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `square_me'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: 'I am getting an error' What error?

Comment: You could also try Nuitka http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html#.  But it won't help if you don't read error messages - nothing will.  Tell us what the error message was - error messages are your friends.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the error. Updated the question with the error. When I am compiling the C code, it is not able to locate the function "square_me" inside "square_number.pyx"

Comment: @cdarke Thanks for pointing to Nuitka. Even in Nuitka, it is throwing the same error. I did the following in Nuitka.                       a) first, I created a simple "square_of_a_number" function in python and b) after installing Nuitka,I created a .so through the command (nuitka --module PYTHON_MODULE.py).                                   Even though the above statement created PYTHON_MODULE.so, I am unable to read the .so from C. I am still getting the same error (which is undefined reference to `square_of_a_number`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change square_number.pyx to:

```
cdef public int square_me(int x):
    return x * x
```

After running the "setup.py" it will generate the header file "square_number.h".
Include that in your main application. See below:

change your "main" function to something like:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "square_number.h"

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    initsquare_number();
    printf("%d",square_me( 4 ) );
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

While compiling this make sure you link against libpython.so and libsquare_number.so
You will also need to take care of include directory search path for "Python.h" by giving -I flag to gcc.

For more information see: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am able to read the shared object from the C Code you have provided. I have a couple of questions. After a shared object is prepared from Cython, why do we have to use "Py_Initialize()" function. Shouldn't the Shared object be independent of python language. And another question is that since we have to link libpython.so and libsquare_number.so, I am assuming that we need python and the python module to be installed in the machine whereever this c code would be compiled

Comment: This is a "python module". It is supposed to be used by python interpreter. something like "import square_number".
These shared objects will not work without python interpreter. 
About Py_Initialize(), it initializes the interpreter and sets up the modules like __main__, sys, sys.path.
Assume your pyx file using "import sys", cython relies on interpreter to take case of these imports.
About, libpython.so. yes, target system must have python installed. Or other way would be to link against static
python library ( libpython.a ). But that will increase your executable size. So its a trade-off

Comment: @Icarus3 If I want to test this program on a machine in which python is not installed, how would i do that? How to simulate that python is not installed?

Comment: Followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459248/linux-how-to-simulate-environment-is-which-python-is-not-installed

Answer (score 0):

I do not remember the details of this, I may be able to give a more detailed answer later once I have. However the basics are that Cython puts the python functions through a name mangling function before exporting the C compatible SOs. Python then understands this same name mangling when it imports a Cython module so can call the correct functions.

What you need to do is use an SO scanning library on the cython module to fund out what the functions are actually called. To do this as a one off try running:

`readelf my_cython_so.so`

This will provide a dump of the contents of the shared object including the function entry points and names the linker uses. You can then use these names to find the correct functions to call from your code. To automate this in your c code you can use libelf instead.

Answer (score 0):

Converting bytecode to assembly does not involve C. It may involve classes wich are called by C, or call other C classes in a C like manner. But it is still bytecode or assembly respectively. You cannot reverse what never was. Use `objectdump -d -M`. To outline the classes, then if you still need to, convert those classes to C by hand, then be thankful we have python to do that for us.